# PhpStorm 2016.3: Alphabetical order of Project files changed?

Tags: phpstorm

Today I upgraded to the 2016.3 release of PhpStorm, and the first thing I noticed was the structure of my files was altered in the project sidebar window.

I work with Magento and the normal alphabetical file structure prior to 2016.3 would be like:

```
-Block
-Controller
-controller
-etc
-Helper
-Model
```

Now, after the 2016.3 release it is suddenly treating alphabetization differently:

```
-Block
-Controller
-Helper
-Model
-controller
-etc
```

I've tried to find an setting which would allow me to dictate how to organize my file structure to appear how I want (strictly alphabetical, case-insensitive), but I am unable to find any.

Does anyone know where I can find a setting to fix this? My current searches are coming up empty. Maybe I'm not searching the right keywords.

Comment: I just made the same upgrade and not seeing this change.  I did notice in the settings dropdown for the window (little gear), there is a `sort by type`, maybe that is on?

Comment: No, it is not. Maybe it's just a quirk with my installation if you're not seeing the same kind of behavior.

Comment: Looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160381; can't recreate with my setup though...

Comment: Thanks, @lena, I submitted a comment to the ticket with an image. It's probably one of those weird quirks that unless certain settings are *just so*, it won't replicate.